# equicontinuity question

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some trouble with the following problem:

Is the family of function $f_{ab} (x) = \frac{(a-x)(x-b)}{(a-b)} $ if $b \leq x \leq a$ and 0 otherwise. Then is  $f_{ab}$ equicontinuous when $a,b$ are integers? I know the definition of equicontinuity, but having both $a$ and $b$ is throwing me off, as I'm used to having just an $n$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Easy form:
$$f'_{ab}(x)={2x-a-b\over b-a}$$
is a straight line, so
$$-1=f'_{ab}(a)\le f'_{ab}(x)\le f'_{ab}(b)=1,$$
and bounded derivative implies easily equicontinuity.